Layer 3D to Feature Class in ArcGIS Pro producing Multipatch features shorter than Extruded Polygons
I've been extruding polygons (max height extrusion) by a proposed height field, creating multipatch features using Layer 3D to feature class and then using Select By Location: Intersect 3D to find features that are in close proximity to sight lines.  This has been working well for about a year.  Starting today, the multipatch output is about 5% to 15% shorter than the extruded polygons. Anyone have any experience with this issue or have any suggestions?

The output from the Layer 3D to Feature Class tool started defaulting to setting the elevation setting to "features are at absolute height" instead of "features are on the ground".

Is it just the top that is lower, or is the bottom of the multipatch also lower than the extruded polygon?  (You may have to turn off any surface or basemap layers to see this.)

Please [Edit] the question to specify anything that changed recently (e.g., Pro release, surface data source,...)
